# How to convert elasticsearch date field into typestamp field

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

ElasticSearch log outputs time as a `date` type. For example `Mar 3, 2021 @ 11:59:30.705`

How can I convert it to timestamp using python? Say the output will be something like `1614730500000`

I specifically need to convert it to milliseconds.

I used the below code

```
import time
import datetime
s = 'Mar 3, 2021 @ 11:59:30.705'
form = '%b %d, %Y @ %H:%M:%S.%fz'
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, form).timetuple())
```

But it shows error

```
ValueError: time data 'Mar 3, 2021 @ 11:59:30.705' does not match format '%b %d, %Y @ %H:%M:%S.%fz'
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution resolves it

```
from datetime import datetime

epoch = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
s = 'Mar 3, 2021 @ 11:59:30.705'
form = '%b %d, %Y @ %H:%M:%S.%f'

def unix_time_millis(datetime):
    return (datetime - epoch).total_seconds() * 1000.0

current_date = datetime.strptime(s, form)
print (unix_time_millis(current_date))
```